# Why is my empty DIV rendering as a dot on screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>&nbsp;</div>` which has the following styles:

```
background-position: 0 bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 0.01em;
overflow: hidden;
```

As far as I can tell, this should simply not appear on the site, but it renders as a dot similar to a full stop instead.

Changing the `font-size` to anything larger than 0.01em makes the dot disappear.

(The div doesn't accomplish anything, but was recently noticed on a customers site and we wish to find out how this could happen?)

Any ideas what's causing it to render as a dot? Or render at all?

Comment: What color is it? The default font color? I made a fiddle to test it but I don't see a thing: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/jcRQB/ Could you provide a live example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I think the more important question is why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve? Also dot not visible in Chrome

Comment: What happens if you individually remove the other styles? Does it need all of them?

Comment: I've no idea why it was done in the first place, I just noticed it recently and was curious as to how it occurred. I have removed the offending DIV as it didn't do anything in the first place.

Comment: Well I'm still curious :) What browser did you get that behavior? Let me guess: IE? ;) What version?

Comment: Firefox 8.0, looks fine in Chrome and IE8 at least.

Comment: @Houdmont: I still don't see it even on FF8. Do you see it @ the jsfiddle of BoltClock? Can it be some plugin?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Maybe it's the pure-whiteness. I'll let it gather dust and come back later and see if it shows up then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white-space will show. It is considered to have content, so it will display. In this case, as a dot.

The `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking white-space and is treated differently by the browser than a normal white-space. For example, if you have the following element:

```
<span>&npsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

it will render with 3 spaces in the element. That is, the equivalent of three `&nbsp;` character widths will be rendered in the span. This is often used by new developers to indent text instead of using CSS, but we know better, don't we ;)

On the other hand, the following:

```
<span>   </span>
```

will render as a span element, and some browsers will consider it's content empty and will not render unless it is given an explicit `height` and `width` (and `display` in this case) or a `border`, or `padding` which will give it a calculable `width` and `height`.

Comment: Why would a non-breaking-space be displayed as a dot?

Comment: So what you're saying is that when you compress a whitespace enough, it renders as actual pixels? Instead of just space?

Comment: Because you are using a non-breaking space, it will show. If you were to just use a regular space, it would not. But the `&nbsp;` is an actual character and will be rendered as such on the page. I'll edit to explain more :)

Comment: @Ktash: I still don't get it. :P Isn't the `nbsp` a whitespace character just like a 'normal' space when it comes to (not) displaying it? Ah I see you're edit that would be great.

Comment: @PeeHaa I've edited it. I'll add more detail if you're still confused on it :)

Comment: A space is a space not a dot, that's what we have `&middot;` for.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder my guess from the code is that the `background-image` which is hinted at with the CSS is what is actually rendering as a 'dot'

Comment: @Ktash: Well might be just me being stupid but I still don't get it. How can a whitespace ever become a dot (i.e. being displayed). I tried everything to display it like a dot or display it at all (by display I mean really seeing a dot and not just the space). The only way to see it would be to select it. Maybe Op and you mean that?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yeah, see my response to @Interstellar_Coder. My guess is that there is a `background-image` that is in the code (given the CSS provided) that is what is rendering as a 'dot'. It is showing on the screen, but only one `&nbsp;` character width of it is visible, and therefore it looks like a 'dot'. If that is not the case, then the code provided would not display a 'dot' and would not be the issue, but if that's the case, the I don't think we can help without more information.

Comment: Aha that could be the case, but only if the div is set to inline. Otherwise the dot would be a line in my opinion (unless it is a 1px image) since the `div` would use the full width of the container. But you might just be right. Now I'm hoping that @Houdmont can confirm this. Otherwise I'm afraid I can't sleep tonight thinking about this :) Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it appears since you have & nbsp; inside it, which is a whitespace character.

Comment: Even though the font is tiny, surely whitespace should still be whitespace, and never display anything?

Comment: Yeah, what happens if it's removed? Or does any parent element have a border or something like that?

Comment: If the &nbsp; is removed, the problem goes awway. But why does it happen in the first place?

Comment: (There are no borders on parent elements)